# How to resize and shrink the sole root mount LVM physical volume?

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I've selected *LVM* default option and completed *Ubuntu 22.04* installation, but failed to resize and shrink the sole root mount LVM physical volume afterwards.

*Method 1:*

```
# mount -t ext4
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root on /

# pvscan
PV /dev/sda2 VG vgubuntu lvm2 [SIZE]  
Total: 1 [SIZE]

# resize2fs -p /dev/vgubuntu/root [NEW_SIZE]
Online shrinking not supported.
(Note: NEW_SIZE is smaller yet big enough.)

# umount /dev/vgubuntu/root
target is busy.

# pvresize --setphysicalvolumesize [NEW_SIZE] /dev/sda2
cannot resize to [SMALL_NUM] extents as [NUM] are allocated.
```

*Method 2:* open *Disks* GUI, but *Resize...* option grayed out on */dev/vgubuntu/root*.

*Method 3:* open *GParted* GUI, can't shrink */dev/sda2* despite *Resize/Move* option available.

*Method 4:* boot into [recovery/maintenance mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode), same as *Method 1*

So, how to resize and shrink it to make a second physical partition?